# Does Firebase storage has a REST service API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, firebase-realtime-database

In my project, I need to upload some images and data, the problem is, I have a Back-end in ASP.NET WebApi to manage all that, so I can't send it on my Android Client, so I was wondering if the Firebase storage has a RestService because I could save the files and data through my WebApi, I only found a REST Service on Firebase RealTime!

`https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install first a package for firebase:
then use it as below:

```
Firebase.goOnline();
var amOnline = new Firebase(appConfig.Firebase.apiUrl + "/.info/connected");
var unread = new Firebase(appConfig.Firebase.apiUrl); 
//'https://yourdatabase.firebaseio.com/'


//Your path to find or load data:
var userRef = new Firebase(appConfig.Firebase.apiUrl + "/users/" + userId + "/status");
```

then find a method to get data from it like:

```
var ref = new Firebase(appConfig.Firebase.apiUrl + "/users/" + userId);
var profile = $firebaseObject(ref);
```

here you can find data of particular user

Comment: But what I want is, be able to make POST and GET from my WebApi to Firebase Storage, and which package ?